# SSH connect GCP

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, ansible, terraform

I at the deadlock. I try to connect to the created VM over SSH, but nothing comes out. Added the following entries to the terraform

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "/bin/echo -e \"${element(random_string.password.*.result, count.index)}\n${element(random_string.password.*.result, count.index)}\" | /usr/bin/passwd root"
 ]
connection {
  type            = "ssh"
  user            = "root"
  private_key     = file(var.privat_google_key)
  agent           = false
  timeout         = "5m"
  host            = google_compute_instance.webserver[count.index].network_interface[0].access_config[0].nat_ip
 }
}

...

resource "google_compute_project_metadata_item" "ssh-keys" {
  key   = "ssh-keys"
  value = file(var.pub_google_key)
}
```

ssh-keys is added to instance.

When I finish, I get

```
google_compute_instance.webserver[0] (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
google_compute_instance.webserver[0] (remote-exec):   Host: 1.1.1.1
google_compute_instance.webserver[0] (remote-exec):   User: root
google_compute_instance.webserver[0] (remote-exec):   Password: false
google_compute_instance.webserver[0] (remote-exec):   Private key: true
google_compute_instance.webserver[0] (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
google_compute_instance.webserver[0] (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
google_compute_instance.webserver[0] (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
google_compute_instance.webserver[0]: Still creating... [5m0s elapsed]


Error: timeout - last error: SSH authentication failed (root@35.247.121.86:22): ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

When I try to connect by ssh from the terminal, I get

```
ssh -i [PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY] [USERNAME]@[EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS]

root@1.1.1.1: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I tried different options to add a key, but I always get forbidden access to the host. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

SSH for Root user is disabled by default on GCP. You will have to use a specific user to connect, you will still have root permissions. If you absolutely must connect using root account which is **not recommended** I suggest using a pre-built image or start-up scripts where you can enable it as described [here](http://fnctn.com/technology/command-line/add-remote-root-ssh-login-capability-to-google-cloud-platform-vm-instance/), but I will not cover in this answer.

So, to achieve a connection on Terraform with a specific user you need to:

1. Change the connection user configuration in TF

```
connection {
  user            = "alexey"
  ...
}
```

2. Change the metadata SSH KEY to contain the username with the publickey in the format described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys).

```
ssh-rsa [KEY_VALUE] [USERNAME]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was still helped by the comand /Users/Husky/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud compute --project sturdy-sentry-276613 ssh --zone "us-west1-c" standard-webserver "--verbosity = debug. Using debug, I saw a connection to a remote host, which helped to understand my problems.